# Подскажите как так получается. Объекта нет, а методы его использовать можно

Tags: c++

Как такое возможно. Почему этот код работает? Это фича или баг?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Obj{
public:
   Obj(){}
   void fuu(){
       int a=0;
       ++a;
       std::cout << a;
   }

};


int main() {

    Obj* obj= nullptr;
    obj->fuu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Есть вероятность, что произодёт форматирование диска. Не советую исполнять такой код :)

Comment: @cppquestions откуда такая вероятность? где тут вообще обращение к диску?

Comment: @pinguin это популярная страшилка, означающая что при UB программа может делать что угодно

Comment: Вам ответили уже, поэтому теперь я хочу вам задать вопрос: подскажите, почему нельзя писать просто:  struct Obj{   void fuu(){  std::cout << 1;}     
   void callFuu(){ fuu();   }  };  Чем вам так нравится писать лишнее? Я вам этот вопрос задал, потому что у многих замечал такую страсть придать сложный вид своему тривиальному коду.... И во вторых,  лучше указать константность этих функции, показав, что это не модификатор

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan хехе, согласен. Ерунду написал. Исправил. А ответ прост, я не знал из за чего это происходит, поймал этот баг утром, тогда же и поправил. А эта сложность, следствие того что, не получалось повторить, до тех пор пока не навертел всего вот этого.

Comment: [KISS-принцип](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это код приводит к *неопределенному поведению*. А уж всякие "методы использовать можно" является лишь проявлением этого неопределенного поведения.

Выражение `obj->fuu()` по определению интерпретируется как `(*obj).fuu()`, т.е. содержит применение оператора `*` к нулевому указателю. Формально, индирекция через нулевой указатель вызывает неопределенное поведение.

---

Как вы сами, наверное, понимаете, на практике невиртуальные методы классов - это фактически просто "синтаксический сахар", надстроенный над "обычными С-шными" функциями со скрытым дополнительным параметром `this`. Поэтому ничего удивительного в том, что в вашем примере все "работает" нет.

Однако при более внимательном рассмотрении можно все таки увидеть завязку С++ компиляторов на то, что указатель `this` не должен и не может быть нулевым. Например, в оптимизированном коде компилятор GCC полагает, что `this` является заведомо ненулевым (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9895fc989a6bc219). Clang как минимум предупреждает о такой возможности (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9c24db6fc52a982). Существуют и другие проявления этого явления.

Comment: А что именно приводит к неопределенному поведению?

Comment: @Nik: Дополнил.